# I can't connect Joomla! remotely with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla, cpanel

I have two hosting (1: IP 192.186.234.192 and 2: IP 74.116.84.169), and I have Joomla website files on hosting 1, Joomla mysql database on hosting 2, both hosting 1 and 2 have Cpanel administration.
I want run Joomla website on host1 by linked it remotely to mysql database on host 2

Steps that I made:

1. In hosting 2 added IP address for hosting 1 in (Remote MySQL).
2. In Joomla configuration.php file I have changed database section like:

   var $host = '74.116.84.169';
   var $user = 'artjour';
   var $password = 'abc@123';
   var $db = 'apuser';
3. I also have changed the host name by server name like:

   var $host = 'servername.mydomainname.com';

But unfortunately:(, Could not connect to MySQL, please it's very important for me to know what's my wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to ping a server?

Answer (score 1):

Use a small PHP script like this to see the error other then "Could not connect to MySQL":

```
<?php

$db_host = "123.456.789"; 
$db_name = "database"; 
$db_user = "user"; 
$db_pass = "password"; 
$db_table_prefix = "prefix_";



GLOBAL $errors;
GLOBAL $successes;

$errors = array();
$successes = array();

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
GLOBAL $mysqli;

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Conn Error = " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, I have tried this code, Error detail is : Conn Error = Can't connect to MySQL server on '74.116.84.169' (110)

Comment: Did you try to run it on server: 74.116.84.169 with $db_host = "localhost"; ?
To see or the MySQL server is actually working on the public domain.

Comment: Yes, work fine on 74.116.84.169 server with localhost

Comment: If its working on 74.116.84.169 then the error  will be for 99% remote SQL connection ...
Please can you add a wildcard (%) for the host instead the ip 192.186.234.192 by the settings of remote SQL connection?

Comment: How can I use wildcard (%) ?

Comment: Please read here:http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/enable-remote-mysql-connections-in-cpanel/
Under: "Enabling Remote MySQL in the Domain cPanel Interface"
By Add host, you can set % instead an IP address.

Answer (score 1):

in the hope that this may help someone I resolved the same situation.

I could access from server A and from command line mysql but I also could not connect my remote joomla database, the httpd server side needed selinux setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db=1 to enable apache to connect to the remote database.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to allow remote SQL connection on server2 with Cpanel : 
http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/enable-remote-mysql-connections-in-cpanel/

Comment: Are you sure you IPs are static ?

Comment: @kursus webserver IPs are always static

Comment: @Kursus It's shared hosting, and the IPs mentioned in Cpanel hosting informaion.

Comment: I found this :http://kb.siteground.com/i_have_problems_accessing_my_mysql_database_remotely/ It says you have to prefix MySQL username and database with cpanelusername_. Worth giving a try.